# PyQT GUI freezes when I update several labels' text 30 times in second

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, ros

I wrote a PyQT5 code. It connects to a ROS topic which produces messages with 30 Hz (30 messages in 1 second).

This is an image from part of GUI:
[image]

When a user selects a gaze topic from Combobox, I call `create_subscriber_gaze_information` function with the help of `connect` signal for the combo box.

```
    # create ROS subscriber for gaze information if the value of its combo box changed
    ui.gaze_info_topic_name_value.activated.connect(create_subscriber_gaze_information)
```

`create_subscriber_gaze_information` function creates a ROS subscriber that reads messages from the topic when it becomes available:

```
def create_subscriber_gaze_information():

    # unsubscribe to the previous topic
    if ui.gaze_info_topic_name_value.ros_subs is not None:
        ui.gaze_info_topic_name_value.ros_subs.unregister()

    # create a subscriber
    ui.gaze_info_topic_name_value.ros_subs = rospy.Subscriber(
                                                        name=ui.gaze_info_topic_name_value.currentText(), 
                                                        data_class=gazesense_msgs.msg.TrackedUserArray, 
                                                        callback=show_gaze_information,
                                                        queue_size=1)
```

Whenever a message becomes available (30 times per second), function `show_gaze_information` will be called automatically. This function updates the value of labels in GUI:

```
def show_gaze_information(gaze_msg):
   
    if ui.groupBox_gaze.is_lock == True:
        return

    ui.groupBox_gaze.is_lock = True

    for person in gaze_msg.people:
        
        #################################
        # head info
        #################################
        # set value of head tranlation x
        ui.label_head_translation_x_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.head_pose.transform.translation.x))
        # set value of head tranlation y
        ui.label_head_translation_y_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.head_pose.transform.translation.y))
        # set value of head tranlation z
        ui.label_head_translation_z_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.head_pose.transform.translation.z))
        # set value of head rotation x
        ui.label_head_rotation_x_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.head_pose.transform.rotation.x))
        # set value of head rotation y
        ui.label_head_rotation_y_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.head_pose.transform.rotation.y))
        # set value of head rotation z
        ui.label_head_rotation_z_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.head_pose.transform.rotation.z))
        # set value of head rotation w
        ui.label_head_rotation_w_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.head_pose.transform.rotation.w))
        # set value of is lost
        ui.label_head_is_lost_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.head_pose.is_lost))
        #################################
        # left eye
        #################################
        # set value of left eye orgin x
        ui.label_left_eye_orgin_x_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.gaze.left_eye_ray.origin.x))
        # set value of left eye orgin y
        ui.label_left_eye_orgin_y_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.gaze.left_eye_ray.origin.y))
        # set value of left eye orgin z
        ui.label_left_eye_orgin_z_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.gaze.left_eye_ray.origin.z))
        # set value of left eye dir x
        ui.label_left_eye_dir_x_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.gaze.left_eye_ray.direction.x))
        # set value of left eye dir y
        ui.label_left_eye_dir_y_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.gaze.left_eye_ray.direction.y))
        # set value of left eye dir z
        ui.label_left_eye_dir_z_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.gaze.left_eye_ray.direction.z))
        # set value of left confidence
        ui.label_left_eye_conf_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.gaze.confidence_left.value))
        # set value of is lost
        ui.label_left_eye_is_lost_value.setText("{}".format(person.tracking_info.gaze.is_lost))
 
    ui.groupBox_gaze.is_lock = False
```

However, the problem is that after running the program and selecting a topic from the combo box, it works for up to 10 seconds; after that, everything freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The problem is that I update labels in `show_gaze_information`.

This function is a callback that is called when a message is published on the topic.

To correct the code, in function `show_gaze_information`, the message should be stored in a variable. Nothing should be modified in UI.

Then in main body of code, I added this part:

```
# update gaze infor periodically
timer_gaze = QtCore.QTimer()
timer_gaze.timeout.connect(update_gaze_information)
timer_gaze.setInterval(500)
timer_gaze.start()
```

This code periodically calls `update_gaze_information` every 0.5 seconds. Now, in this function, I update labels in the UI.

Comment: The *real* problem is that the subscriber is most certainly running on its own thread, and widgets are *not* thread-safe, so you cannot access them from external threads. You should start the subscriber and keep it alive in a separate thread, and emit a signal whenever updates are necessary, then connect that signal to the function that finally updates the labels. For this you will most certainly do some more research in subclassing, as it seems clear that you're trying a more simplistic/functional approach that doesn't really work well with threading and OOP in general.

Comment: You are right. My method for solving it is not a good OOP way. However, It fixed the problem. In future, I will replace it with a better version.

Yes, Subscribe (ROS) is a separate thread